# I am looking to melt some leftover acrylic into a mould, at home. Are there fumes that I should be worried about?

Tags: material-selection, plastic, safety

So, the title just about sums it up.

I've cut some acrylic sheets to make vitrines for some painting frames and I have some leftover strips of acrylic.

I have an idea of what to use the acrylic for, but that would require melting it into a mould to make it into a small block.

I've read that acrylic melts at between 160ºC to 190ºC - which are temperatures that any oven at home can easily reach - however, I'm concerned about whether melting the acrylic will release any noxious fumes or not. Because, if so, I certainly won't be doing it at home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of links that describe toxic fumes from burning or laser-cutting acrylic.  Apparently, the risk also applies to the molten plastic, as you would encounter with 3D printing or molding.  According to [Everything You Need To Know About Acrylic (PMMA)](https://www.creativemechanisms.com/blog/injection-mold-3d-print-cnc-acrylic-plastic-pmma):

> ...fumes from 3D printing with acrylic or from the molten material used during injection molding should not be inhaled and ... should be conducted in a well ventilated facility to avoid the potentially hazardous effects of gaseous polymer.

Answer (score 3):

Acrylic is also very easy to scorch, for example when line bending or vacuum forming. I doubt you'd be able to melt it evenly without it getting a brown crust in places.